# Xcode: Add git server: "Server is disabled"

Tags: xcode, git, gitlab

I just set up a small GitLab server on my Proxmox box and want to use it for my Xcode projects. I create a new project in Xcode and under "Create new git repository on", I select "Add new server". Then, I enter the address (ssh://git.tobi-soft.de) and give it my username and password (I tried both my username and email address).

But then Xcode comes back and says "Server is disabled". Is this a configuration issue on my server, a bad URL or simply a bug in Xcode? (Xcode 5 DP3)

Thanks

Tobias Timpe

Comment: Can you `ssh` to your server normally using the same username and password?

Comment: I have set up public key auth on the server meaning I added my Mac's public key to my account on the GitLab interface. Do I need an actual PAM user or how do I tell Xcode to use the right private key?

Comment: *“Then, I enter the address (ssh://git.tobi-soft.de) and give it my username and password (I tried both my username and email address).”* So did you actually use a private key here?

Comment: I gave GitLab my private key in the web interface, but Xcode asks for username and password and there I tried the login from the GitLab web interface.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error message with Xcode 5 DP3. Can't really go into much more detail (NDA); and can't discuss it anywhere else as the Dev Forums are down!